# Spartan programming... What is it good for?

Tags: programming-practices, methodology

We are being forced to use [Spartan](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/spartan-programming.html) [programming](http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Spartan_programming) on a project, to everybody's dismay. So I get it, it makes the methods really short and it handles the simple cases first. But is it really worth the price of the code looking like something out of the Obfuscated C Code contest?

Can you see it being useful for something?

Comment: What the heck is "spartan programming"?  Can you provide a link for us ignorant folk?

Comment: You're "forced to use Spartan programming on a project"?! How does that work? I mean, I can (to a point) imagine being forced to use (an editor/a VSC/...) on a project, but how can one be forced to use a certain approach?

Comment: **This is Sparta!**

Comment: Looks like something between best practices and extreme dogmatism.  See it as a fun challenge, and it'll be... fun.  Also looks like a waste of time.

Comment: If you end up with code that should be entered into an obfuscated contest, despite any euphemism, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @Dean Harding: I upvote your comment, "just because" :)

Comment: @Rook It works like this: "do it or it'll hurt your grade in this project".

Comment: @EpsilonVector: Ah, so this is a school project, not something in "the real world"? Then I would just suck it up and do the work. Perhaps the professor is trying to teach you that blind adherence to dogmatic rules is typically detrimental to your ability to work efficiently. Or maybe he's just sadistic... I know many professors who are ;-)

Comment: @EpsilonVector - Oh, I didn't realize this was for a school project. (what Dean said sums up the rest).

Comment: @Rook, it also goes... "do it like this, or you're fired." - and a methodology should be far more enforcible than an editor.

Comment: @EpsilonVector - the second article (I didn't read Jeff's) doesn't sound particularly insane (re: your obfuscation comment), and seems to be more concerned with reducing bloated classes, poorly scoped variables and bad nesting.

Comment: @Slomojo - Methodologies are rarely enforced "to the letter", and more often than not they can be worked around. Also, unless it's something technically obvious (and for a good reason) it is almost never putted like that.

Comment: @Slomojo Yeah, it's less insane than I thought it was. I was going by my team-mates' description because the link we were given to learn from didn't work at the time so I couldn't check it for myself. I still don't think there's cause to go to extremes to enforce the parts that really are good practice.

Comment: @EpsilonVector, The methodology is "extreme" by one definition, to then take it to further extremes would be foolish. But as a teaching exercise, this is useful, because (providing you're being taught by a pragmatist) all the goals of spartan programming are useful lessons that can be applied, conservatively, to general programming, with good results.

Comment: I love our project supervisor's reaction to this. Upon finding my question he went to the project forums and posted a message encouraging everybody to engage in the proud programmer tradition of syntax holy wars and complaining about code conventions imposed by the higher ups. Cheers to him.

Comment: The methodology looks sane and your supervisor's encouragement of "holy wars" suggests that he has a sense of humor. It sounds like a pretty good class. Let us know how it turns out.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Many of the tenants of Spartan programming just seem like good practise to me. For example, keeping methods short, minimizing the scope of variables, minimizing the number of parameters to a method, or methods to a class, etc. These are all good things and exactly what you should be striving for.

But then there's stuff like [minimizing character count](http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Spartan_programming#Metrics), [minimizing token counts](http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Token_count,_spartan_reduction_of), [ternarization](http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Ternarization) (seriously?), etc which really make no sense.

I think my main problem with it is exemplified by [this quote](http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/Spartan_programming):

> But, spartan programming is more than just a technical coding style, in that is has a single underlying, unifying principle---minimalism and simplicity taken to extremes.

Anything "taken to extremes" rings alarm bells to me.

Comment: Anyone said "programming"? :p

Comment: ternarization is interesting, in the first case cited in the linked paper, it's a good idea, in the second... hmmm ok, I'd let that go, but to take ternarization to silly extremes (e.g. nested ternaries) is, well, silly.

Comment: @Slomojo: The real WTF on that page is the sections on "Automatic ternarization"...

Comment: that regex is pretty awesome, as long as you review each ternarization I don't see a big problem with it. As long as they are still readable they're ok. - As you say, it's the extremes (or perhaps more correctly, extremists) that would be the problem.

Comment: +1 for Anything "taken to extremes" rings alarm bells to me.

Comment: I'm not allowed to substitute "tenets" for "tenants" (too small an edit). If anyone else has an edit for this answer, consider adding in this one.

Comment: All four of the links in your post are now dead.

Answer (score 4):

Now that looked disturbingly familiar. Even the minimizing on the tokens, although not taken to the extremes. I rather use fname than filename for example, out for output, x for the data input, n for counts, l for lengths and so on. lx would be length of x, ly length of y,... you get the drift.

Plus, as I often manipulate large datasets in scientific applications, I use the index facilities in R a lot. When I write out all those indices, the code hurts my eyes. So index becomes id, or even just i.

Even more, the specific loop structures in R (the apply family) often demands of function declaration within the apply call. In those cases I always use x,y,z,... These functions are often one or two lines, so it's clear where it's coming from, and it doesn't clutter the screen.

It's not a bad thing, as long as you have some naming conventions that are coherent through the complete code, and you supply comments to explain the more obscure variable names. In the end, it makes code more readible to me than a long train of camels hobbling over the screen.

Comment: I agree that shorter variables are often easier to read than extremely long variable names. As I said in my answer, 'Anything "taken to extremes" rings alarm bells to me' and that goes both ways. Your ultimate goal is to maximize readability, regardless of particular character counts.

Comment: You say "..it makes code more readible to me..."; I put the emphasis in "to me". When your code is used and maintained by other dozen people, then your variables and logic must make sense to *them* as well as *you*. In those cases, your conventions and abbreviations may not be so clear. :-)

Comment: @Cesargon: It's a matter of documenting the conventions.

Comment: @Dean I agree completely on that. Yet, I notice a tendency to the other extreme, noteably in some specific programming languages. Jave comes to mind...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an article that discusses the benefits of spartan programming

http://ssdl-wiki.cs.technion.ac.il/wiki/index.php/SendAnEmail_case_study

Comment: It's a joke, right? Minimising variable name length, minimising number of variables... gosh, reminds me of my MSX days!

Comment: I'm not approving it :) but the article explains it better then I can.

Comment: I know, I know.

Comment: Shouldn't these things shown in the article belong to every refactoring action? I didn't know that this was called "Spartan Programming", but generally I try to care about these things while I write code (apart from the variable name length, but I haven't found that issue in the article anyway)

Comment: Yeah I'm familiar with that link, except that it used to not load when we tried to access it a while ago... OK so it's less insane than my team members made it sound, but I still side with CaesarGon on this one...

Comment: Links to articles are not complete answers, you must post your own content. Also, that link is dead.

Answer (score 2):

This is an accentuation Compactness of the Cs.

1. Correctness
2. Completeness
3. Compactness

No one cares about your code if it isn't correct.

If your code isn't complete (handles every case), then there *are* bugs.

If it isn't compact than you are wasting memory or clock cycles ( compiler optimizations aside )

Note the order here is paramount. The most Compact program is rarely correct. E.G.

```
void main() {
 return 1; 
}
```

Comment: You can make that even more compact if you want to. `void main(){return 1;}`

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I actually program like this, didn't know it had a name. I would say it benefits readability but more in a spatial way... meaning you don't get lost in a soup of code even if you have few lines that are kind of hard to read.

However, I'd say that when you get used to certain constructs you find your way easier in less time than at the very start.

Comment: There is a new version of the spartznizer project, here: https://github.com/SpartanRefactoring/Spartanizer/wiki/Tutorial